# FastReport: Save as Excel 2007 file (.xlsx) VS XML (Excel) table .xls

Tags: c#, sql, .net, report, fastreport

Good day everyone, I have a question about compatibility of Excel-type files in FastReport (version 2020.1.17):

Our company uses FastReport tools to create reports and integrate them into e-docs system.
When the report is build, we have a selection of formats to save from, including excel formats (specifically
**.xlsx for Excel 2007** option and **.xls - for XML (Excel) table**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zB4AQ.png)

The problem is that when the client chooses to build report between 18.09.2023 and 25.09.2023 (is inputed manually through form) using **Excel 2007 option**, it goes with this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERE0r.png)

Table is being built normally when we specify period from 04.09 to 15.09.
Same goes with XML (Excel) table and .xls format, but this time report looks normal regardless of inputed period.

Code tab lookd like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tiPT4.png)

Perhaps I should add some code to solve this problem, but I am not very skilled in C# or maybe there are special plugins, so please, help. Thanks.

Searched through plugins, code solutions, russian-english manual but to no avail

Answer (score -1):

You're facing an issue with FastReport when generating Excel reports for a specific date range. Check date format compatibility, investigate code logic for errors, and debug if needed. Verify data quality and consider software updates or alternative export formats. Ensure language and localization settings are correct, and test with various date ranges to pinpoint the problem. Reach out to FastReport support or community for assistance if necessary.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).